# Keep track of scope in AST using acorn-walk

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree, acorn

I need to keep track of the scope of an AST to arrange all expressions into a hierarchy using acorn-walk in JS. There is very little documentation so I am pretty clueless. Thanks for all the help!